# Implementing IEnumerable<'T> when base class implements IEnumerable

Tags: f#, ienumerable

Is there a succinct way to implement `IEnumerable<'T>` in a type whose base type implements the non-generic `IEnumerable`?  I'm using the `mkEnumerator` function below to do it, but it seems excessive.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Configuration

let mkEnumerator<'T> (e : System.Collections.IEnumerator) =
  { new IEnumerator<'T> with
      member __.Current = e.Current |> unbox
    interface System.Collections.IEnumerator with
      member __.Current = e.Current
      member __.MoveNext() = e.MoveNext()
      member __.Reset() = e.Reset()
    interface IDisposable with
      member __.Dispose() =
        match e with
        | :? IDisposable as d -> d.Dispose()
        | _ -> () }

type MyConfigElement() = 
  inherit ConfigurationElement()

type MyConfigCollection() =
  inherit ConfigurationElementCollection()
  override __.CreateNewElement() = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
  override __.GetElementKey(_) = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
  interface IEnumerable<MyConfigElement> with
    member __.GetEnumerator() = mkEnumerator<MyConfigElement> (base.GetEnumerator())
```

#### Update

Following desco's suggestion, I'm now using:

```
type MyConfigCollection() =
  inherit ConfigurationElementCollection()
  ...
  interface IEnumerable<MyConfigElement> with
    member __.GetEnumerator() = (Seq.cast<MyConfigElement> this).GetEnumerator()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

shorter version of Brian's suggestion:

```
let mkEnum<'T> (ie : System.Collections.IEnumerable) = (Seq.cast<'T> ie).GetEnumerator()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your way looks best.  I guess this is more succinct (I have not tried it end-to-end to ensure it works):

```
let mkEnum<'T>(ie : System.Collections.IEnumerable) 
                       : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<'T> =
    (seq { for x in ie -> unbox x }).GetEnumerator()
```

but I wonder if it allocates more.

As is pointed out by @desco, this is even shorter:

```
let mkEnum<'T> ie = (Seq.cast<'T>(ie)).GetEnumerator()
```

Comment: Hmm, okay. I guess I'll keep what I have. It would be (slightly) better if I could omit the type parameter in `mkEnumerator<MyConfigElement> (base.GetEnumerator())` but it complains: _The member 'GetEnumerator<'a0> : unit -> IEnumerator<'a0>' does not have the correct number of method type parameters. The required signature is 'GetEnumerator : unit -> IEnumerator<MyConfigElement>'._ I thought it might infer it based on the interface type.

Comment: a bit shorter :) let mkEnum<'T> (ie : System.Collections.IEnumerable) = (Seq.cast<'T> ie).GetEnumerator()

Comment: @desco: Good call. [`Seq.cast`](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L36-47) is almost identical to my `mkEnumerator` function.

Comment: @desco: That should probably be the answer.